# No able to display image using a variable

Tags: reactjs

I stored the image name in localstorage.

My local Storage data is:

```
Key:contact
data:[{"id":1,"name":"","query":"","image":"'./Koala.jpg'","price":""}]
```

My code is below

```
  return ( 
        <React.Fragment>
            <h2>Products Cataloge.</h2>
            <div className="container" id="con">
                <div className="row">
                    {this.state.comment.map((item,index)=>(
                        <div className="col-md-4" >
                            <div className="card" id="card1" >
                                <img className="card-img-top" src={require(item.image)} alt="Card image"/>
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h4 className="card-title">{item.name}</h4>
                                    <Link to={`/description/${item.id}`} ><button className="btn btn-primary">View Discription</button></Link> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        ))}
                </div>
           </div>
        </React.Fragment>
     );
```

Comment: what does the code  for `require(item.image)` look like?

Comment: require is built-in function in reactjs library.

Answer (score 0):

For file and url paths you want them to be formatted './path' or "./path"

By setting data.image to `data { image: "'./Koala.jpg'" }` you will be returning the whole string value `'./Koala.jpg'` including the single quotes

```js
const data = {imageGood:" ./Koala.jpg " , imageBad:"'./Koala.jpg'"}

console.log('imageBad' , data.imageBad)    // "'./Koala.jpg'"
console.log('imageGood', data.imageGood)   //  "./Koala.jpg"
```

If you can change the way your data is being populated change:

```
data:[{"id":1,"name":"","query":"","image":"'./Koala.jpg'","price":""}]
```

To:

```
data:[{"id":1,"name":"","query":"","image":"./Koala.jpg","price":""}]
```

If not then you will need to remove them manually. One easy way:

```js
const item = {image:" './Koala.jpg' "}
console.log( item.image.split("'").join('') )
```

Comment: i changed the data but still the immage is not shown on html page

Comment: can you post what your data looks like now? Also are you sure that the images are stored in the same directory (not a sub directory) as the file you're importing into?